# Regex replace text with < in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I am having a hard time with replacing this text with something else .
This XML uses also next lines .

```
     <Need>
        <Need type="money" amount="100"/>
     </Need>
```

I have tried it with this :

```
<Need>([\n]*[a-Z]*)</Need>

<Need>(?:[^\n]*(\n+))+</Need>

<Need>([^\n]*[0->]*[a-Z]*)</Need>

<Need>([^\n]*[a-Z]*)</Need>
```

Non of them worked and 2 deleted the whole text :( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

```
<Need>(.*?)</Need>
```

Replace by:

```
$1
```

Be sure that:

- regular expression is checked.
- . (dot) matches newline is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for extensive search and replace considering white space and new line.

```
[\s]*<Need>[\r\s]*<Need[^/]*/>[\r\s]*</Need>
```